# create PDF with django using python 3

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-3.3

I want to creat a pdf file with django. But I use python 3. Is there already a libary supportign python3?
I found reportlab, pisa, html2py... but I think none support python 3.
I hope something like html2py is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: I just came across Django Easy PDF which is Python 3 compatible and may be more useful:

https://github.com/nigma/django-easy-pdf

Note, however, that as of writing this [xhtml2pdf](https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf) which is a dependency of Django Easy PDF only supports Python 3 if you install the latest beta version with:

```
pip install --pre xhtml2pdf
```

---

WeasyPrint is Python 3 compatible:

http://weasyprint.org/

It's a great library and is easy enough to integrate with Django. Here's a blog post with some suggestions:

http://ampad.de/blog/generating-pdfs-django/

Comment: The problem with weasyprint is embedding fonts. The server must have them installed and most hosts won't let you. I temporarily switched back to python 2.7 and reportlab due to this issue

Comment: Good point. I still like WeasyPrint but just found 'Django Easy PDF' (see edit above) which looks like a good alternative.

Comment: django-easy-pdf depends on xhtml2pdf which is not compatible with python 3

Comment: Weasyprint is the way to go. This worked great for me.

Comment: xhtml2pdf added beta support for Python 3. For now you have to install it with `pip install --pre xhtml2pdf`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather go for a stack described [here](http://www.peregrinesalon.com/blog/2015/06/python-3-django-generating-a-pdf-from-markdown-or-html/) using:

- `wkhtmltopdf` (obtained via apt-get) (info: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)
- `pip install pdfkit` (info: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit)